# Unable to set JWT token as environment variable when user login/sign-up in postman using test script?

Tags: javascript, postman

Unable to set JWT token as environment variable when user login/sign-up in postman set-up using test script. I am using below test script in postman. But that's not working

```
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("jwt", postman.response.json().token);
```

Below is my response

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVmNjViYjZiNzdkYmEyNDM5YzM2NGRiNSIsImlhdCI6MTYwMDUwMjYzNiwiZXhwIjoxNjA4Mjc4NjM2fQ.Pkhdghgdhc8jOVcIendST5YHHeKzX69CwP7F9KgI",
    "data": {
        "user": {
            "_id": "5f65bb6b77dba2439c364db5",
            "name": "vickram",
            "email": "testuser@test.com",
            "password": "$2a$12$TphQKpGCawxaNBJO8UpnIut2dSucCPGgdPt/1KFlO5EtBt7Yy4xUW",
            "__v": 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your response look like?

Comment: Does the console show an error?

Comment: Yeah, getting error that contain 'Cannot read property json of undefined'

Comment: Can you try `pm.response.json().token`?
I can reproduce that error when using `postman.`, I think I recall something that it is deprecated.

Comment: Have you checked if the data is already parsed in JSON?

var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

postman.setEnvironmentVariable("jwt", jsonData.token);

Comment: The `json()` is parsing to json

Comment: The latest versions have intellisense with will tell you the syntax that's needed. `postman.` would only show one option with is `setNextRequest()`. The rest of the commands can be seen when using `pm.`

Answer (score 1):

This will do it: `pm.environment.set("jwt", pm.response.json().token);`

Comment: I have already try these syntax but it's not working

Comment: Yeah, pm of undefined. I think pm got deprecated from postman. In postman when i click on Set an Environment variable then i get this syntax by default:- postman.setEnvironmentVariable("variable_key", "variable_value");

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```js
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("token", jsonData.token);
```

Comment: This would also work but it's using the older syntax. See Christian's answer for the newer syntax.